# How can I extract text before a specific character that can occur multiple times in different places within a single cell

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula, extract, excel-2016

I'm trying to find a single formula(preferable, Excel 2016)/VBA solution that would work in my case. Basically I have a column where every cell contains different text that looks like this

google (@), microsoft (#), hewlett and packard (@), tesla ($), random text i run out of names (@), another random text (%)

where x is different text. I need to extract all values that occur before (@) and (@) can occur up to 3 times within the same cell placed randomly (beginiing, middle, end). the output should look like

google, hewlett and packard, random text i run out of names

what would be the best solution? Thank you!

tried this solution

=CONCATENATE(TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B3,FIND("~~",SUBSTITUTE(B3,"@","~~",1)),LEN(B3))," ",REPT(" ",100),1),100)),",",TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(B3,FIND("~~",SUBSTITUTE(B3,"@","~~",2)),LEN(B3))," ",REPT(" ",100),1),100)))

changing LEFT to RIGHT, but failed - it doesn't pick up the names to the right of (@)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FILTERXML`:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'(@)')]"),"(@)","")
```

If the results do not `SPILL` down (I cannot recall if 2016 has that feature, then you can return the individual results by adding the `INDEX` function and filling down the formula until you get blanks:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE($A$1,",","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'(@)')]"),"(@)",""),ROWS($1:1)),"")
```

[image]

***Results***
[image]

If you really want it in a comma-separated string, and not in separate cells, then you can use, in earlier versions:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'(@)')][1]"),"(@)",""))
& IFERROR(", " &  TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'(@)')][2]"),"(@)","")),"")
& IFERROR(", " &  TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'(@)')][3]"),"(@)","")),"")
```

or, as pointed out by @joswoolley in the comments below, you could use `CONCAT` function which I did not realize was available in Excel 2016:

```
=REPLACE(CONCAT(", "&SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'(@)')]")," (@)","")),1,2,"")
```

***Results***
[image]

Comment: `CONCAT` is available in Excel 2016, so you can use, e.g. `=REPLACE(CONCAT(", "&SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(.,'(@)')]")," (@)","")),1,2,"")`

Comment: @JosWoolley Nice use of `CONCAT`. My *faulty* recollection was that `CONCAT` and `TEXTJOIN` were added the same time, and `TEXTJOIN` wasn't available until 2019.

Comment: I confess that I always have to Google with which versions those functions came into existence!